# Isn't uint256 enough for quantities in weis?

Tags: solidity

I've made a piggy bank and I want to be able to make checks. But it turns out that I can't make payments with more than fifteen zeros. This is normal?

This is my function to register checks:

```
 function setdebtor(address _address, uint _checkId, uint256  _amount) segurity public {
        check[_checkId] = _amount;
        debtor[_address] = true;

}
```

my mappings:

```
mapping(uint => uint256) check;
    mapping(address => bool) debtor;
```

and my pay function:

```
function paycheck(uint _check) public {
        require(debtor[msg.sender]);
        msg.sender.transfer(check[_check]);
        debtor[msg.sender] = false;

    }
```

But if I make checks with amounts greater than fifteen zeros I get the following error:

```
transact to Hucha.setdebtor errored: Error encoding arguments: Error: invalid number value (arg="", coderType="uint256", value=30000000000000000, version=4.0.37) 
>
```

that is the limit of type uint256?

It doesn't make much sense because in this function I introduce quantities with eighteen zeroes without problems ...

```
 function enterFunds(uint amount) public payable {
        require(msg.value == amount);
        emit operations("Ingreso realizado de: ", amount);


    }
```

All the Code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.11;

contract Hucha {

    address owner;
    mapping(address => bool) debtor;
    mapping(uint => uint) check; 


    event operations(string msg, uint amount);



    modifier segurity {
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        _;
    }

    constructor() public {
        owner = msg.sender; 
    }


    function getbalance() view public returns(uint) {
        return address(this).balance;
    }

    function enterFunds(uint amount) public payable {
        require(msg.value == amount);
        emit operations("Ingreso realizado de: ", amount);


    }

     function extractFunds(uint amount) segurity public {
              msg.sender.transfer(amount);
              emit operations("Se han sacado: ", amount);

    }

    function kill() segurity public {
        selfdestruct(msg.sender);
    } 



function paycheck(uint _check) public {
        require(debtor[msg.sender]);
        require(check[_check] != 0); // si no existe el cheque devolvera cero. 
        msg.sender.transfer(check[_check]);
        debtor[msg.sender] = false;

    }

    function setdebtor(address _address, uint _checkId, uint256  _amount) segurity public {
        check[_checkId] = _amount;
        debtor[_address] = true;

    }





}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because of the big number in javascript, you can just add double quotes `"30000000000000000"` to your value

Comment: what!!? Increible. and.. .. why then it works without quotes in this function?
    `function enterFunds(uint 
    amount) public payable {
    require(msg.value == amount);
    emit operations("Ingreso realizado de: ", 
    amount);
    }`

Comment: it shouldn't though. Can you show how do you call this method and the transaction log?

Comment: Of course. I update the question and enter all the code.

Comment: Can you send the exact code that you use when you actually call this transaction from your interface? And the transaction receipt or if the transaction on a public network you can just send the transaction hash

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean by "you really call this transaction from your interface".
I am practicing in Remix and I have not deployed this program on an authentic Ethereum network.
Could you explain why the transaction receipt is necessary? What would you see in the transaction hash?

Comment: ok, you didn't mention remix. remix will automatically add double quotes to big numbers, except if you using scientific notation like 3e16

Comment: Do you use the online version of remix or the local one?

Comment: Online version.  
I don´t use scienific notation.
The only novelty is that I use the new layout ..